# opening closing brackets [ ] not posting back to controller properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, encoding

I have the following characters in a Hidden Field on a view

> ~!@#$%^&*()_-+=][{}|’;:”/.,<>?

inside a form I am posting back to my controller.

I have tried encoding it but it does not encode the `[ ]` characters and this seems to break the binding and the model is not posted back to the controller correctly. I know this because I have removed these brackets and when I remove them it works

I display the

> ~!@#$%^&*()_-+=][{}|’;:”/.,<>?

using `@Html.Raw` but I am unable to place a `Html.Raw` inside a `@Hidden` which I think could solve the problem

What is the correct way of posting back data like

> ~!@#$%^&*()_-+=][{}|’;:”/.,<>?

to the controller?

Comment: You could use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`

Comment: I have tried HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() but it did not make a difference. Where would I use the UrlEncode? in the view? in the controller?

Comment: You can use it while binding to the hidden Field

Comment: @Html.Raw(Html.Hidden(Model.Description)) - didnt work

Comment: use it as `@Html.Hidden("Name",HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Model.Description))`

Comment: just tried @Html.Hidden(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Model.Description)) - didnt work either - didn't try putting in the 'Name' though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89765/discussion-between-kurasa-and-tushar-gupta).